# Is there open wave/sound arts?

Tags: audio, wav

I love the [Open Clip Art Library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Clip_Art_Library), I'll be glad to hear if there is something for wave/sound simliar to the openclipart. So I can use them in my applications for playing sound effects for user interaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [FreeSound](http://www.freesound.org/).

> Freesound is a collaborative database of Creative Commons Licensed sounds. Browse, download and share sounds.

Also, check [Game Content Resources](http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/Game_Content_Resources#Sound) which has more links. You can also consider using an audio editing application (like Audacity) to remix/build upon those sounds.